# Using Red Hat Docker image as base image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I am considering using https://access.redhat.com/containers/#/registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7 as a base image for my Dockerfile instead of getting some random image in DockerHub. The main reason is the vetting process the images undergo.

Once any additional dependencies are installed, the resulting image will be pushed to a private Docker Hub repository. Is this a valid process or is there a disadvantage that I've missed?

Comment: Is this an issue of trusting the upstream image? Or, keeping control of the images that you use for your use case?

Comment: Actually it's both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have access to the `FROM` image registry, you are totally free to choose where to pull from and where to push to.

Comment: I agree. I was just wondering if I'm missing something and thereby doing something contrary to best practices.